# Soft question -- I need books and exercise books that will be working on my fundamental skills.

Tags: self-learning, education

I need help, urgently. I acquired a book called: Mathematics, Its Content, Method and Meaning. Now the problems is the book doesn't provide me with any exercises. I was searching for a book that would work on fundamental skills so basic skills and then gradually progressing to more advanced skills. I really need a book that will optimize all aspects of maths skills; I seem to be very rusty, and the last time I studied maths was at GCSE, but I seem to have lost many skills -- and these skills are basic! I need to gain these skills again. And again, I want to improve every aspect that there is. I want to see every single method, too. I'll give an example: Basic Mathematics by Serge Langey. I heard the book is marred with many errors, so I am reluctant to spend my money on a "flawed gem". If I seem to be slightly nebulous, please do forgive me, as I am in a rush. Thank you, and any response is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Ethan Block's _Proofs and Fundamentals_ (http://www.amazon.com/Proofs-Fundamentals-Course-Abstract-Mathematics/dp/0817641114 ) is a good choice. You could also use https://brilliant.org/

Comment: The hard bit of your question is to understand what kind of math level you want to achieve. GCSE seems some British school level / degree. I sure there are preparation guides for such a goal.

Comment: If you mean [this book](http://www.amazon.com/dp/0486409163), I'm afraid that this 3-volume work (I have the original hardback 3-volume version) is way too broad in scope for anyone to usefully suggest a companion book for working on fundamental skills.

Comment: That book looks interesting, but amazon manages not to preview any meat.

Comment: Check [these books](http://www.4shared.com/rar/ywxu5Wjfce/books.html).

Comment: @mvw: If your comment is to the 3-volume (in its original version) English translation of a Russian work, you can find discussions about in math StackExchange [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/62190/mathematical-equivalent-of-feynmans-lectures-on-physics) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/541684/an-overview-of-analysis), among other places. There's also a review in [Amer. Math. Monthly 73 (1966), pp. 913-914](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2314225) (requires JSTOR access).

Comment: mvw, I think I need preparation and a lot of it! Starting from the basics and gradually making my path to advanced mathematics.

Comment: metacompactness, I scanned everything, and that level is just far too easy!

Comment: Anymore suggestions? I would really appreciate it if someone gave me a concise but meticulous answer. I just need some advice on what  books to get.

Answer (score -1):

Having only just finished my gcse last year this book (http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/aw/d/1446900185/ref=mp_s_a_1_3?qid=1452527349&sr=8-3&pi=SY200_QL40&keywords=gcse+maths+edexcel&dpPl=1&dpID=51TqDXPEC-L&ref=plSrch) really helped its a revison guide for all you need at gcse and it explains it all clearly and concicely. And at 3.99 at the moment its not going to break the bank, also there is another book that you can also buy with other questions in but the method is the same. Hope i helped!

Comment: i don't think OP wants a GCSE textbook...